# Parsing WSDL through PHP SoapClient

Tags: php, wsdl, dynamics-crm-2011, soap-client

I'm trying to connect to Dynamics CRM via PHP. PHPs inbuilt SoapClient parses the WSDL successfully but I want/need to be able to look at some of the tags in the WSDL and extract information from it.

My question is thus:

*Is there a clever way to extract and re-parse the WSDL via the inbuilt SOAP Client?*

I could obviously use SimpleXML / DomDocument / Curl libraries to parse the WSDL but then I'd have to re-write functionality such as processing namespace imports which I'm trying to avoid.

Any help / suggestions even if it is that parsing without SoapClient is the best solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe all you really need is `$client->__getFunctions()` and `$client->__getTypes()`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but unfortunately those two functions do not return the information I require as they are specific to the SOAP operations of the WSDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **soapui**

This is an excelent tool for easy and fast check of all wsdl functions.

Download:

- here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/loadui/files/

Tutorias:

- http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/your-first-soapui-project.html

Comment: Thanks Diogo, unfortunately I need to parse the XML in my application. I've resorted to using DOMDocument for now.

Comment: And if you do just this: $client = new SoapClient($url.'?wsdl');